# Generate CSR for SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to add SSL to a Apache/Linux sever.

Do I have to generate CSR from the same server which I need to add SSL?

Also when I add SSL in Apache sever, can I omit mentioning key file like below?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www.example.com.cert
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And no, I don't think you can omit specifying the keyfile.  Why would you want to?

Comment: @MadHatter I received the CRT files from client. But not the key file.

Comment: Then the certificate is unusable.  You need the private keyfile that the certificate corresponds to, in order to use the certificate.  End of story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not *have to* generate the CSR on the server where it is going to be used, but for certificates only used on a single server, it is highly recommended that you generate the keys on the server and never let it leave that host.

You ***will*** need to let Apache know where the private key can be found however.

Think of the private and public key as a set of unique English-Korean dictionaries.

The browser speaks English only - so does Apache

When the browser wants to send something to Apache in secrecy, it obtains the English-Korean dictionary (*the certificate/public key*) from Apache and translates the secret message to Korean.

When Apache receives the secret message, it needs the Korean-English dictionary (*the private key*) to translate it in order to make sense of it.

Without the private key, everything sent to the web server is pure korean and apache won't know how to respond

Comment: To any Korean-speaking users: I apologize in advance, I'm not trying to imply that the Korean language is weirdly padded and prone to implementation errors - It's just cryptic from an ignorant western language perspective, that's all